# Wpf - Combobox Binding to a DateTime ArrayList

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have a static `ArrayList` of `DateTimes`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <col:ArrayList x:Key="startHours">
        <sys:DateTime>0:00</sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime>0:30</sys:DateTime>
        <!-- .... -->
    </col:ArrayList>
</Window.Resources>
```

I want to fill a combobox with `hour:minute` formatted dates, so I do

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbFinish" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource startHours}}" 
          ItemStringFormat="t"/>
```

The Items are formatted ok - `hour:minute`, but when I select an item, the `cmbFinish.Value` has the default `DateTime.ToString()` format. What am I missing? I need the `cmbFinish.Value` to be in `hour:minute` format.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a `Value` property in ComboBox class. Were you thinking about the SelectedValue property?
In this case cast its value to a DateTime `(DateTime)cmbFinish.SelectedValue` that you can then convert to the string format you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you are right, I mean cmvFinish.SelectedValue. I'm sorry if I didn't made myself clear, but I don't get what you mean by (DateTime)cmbFinish.SelectedValue and convert it..

Comment: If your combobox is editable, the SelectedValue property may contain a DateTime or null. You have to check it before casting the SelectedValue into a DateTime. In both cases, you can read the ComboBox.Text value to read the typed text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry... My combobox has a `IsEditable`(I forgot to add it into the question) property set to `True`. According to [social msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/4436daf7-aa66-4555-a970-53b21909cfb9/) in this case `.SelectedValue` will pick up the source value, even if it has a converter applied.

If the `IsEditable` property is set to `False`, there is no difference in the Items format  and .`SelectedValue` format. Right now I think the best way is to bind to a converted into strings ArrayList.